# Open local app from button on SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

On a SharePoint Online list I would like to add a custom button.
This button should open a local application (like Word).

When I try in my browser

```
ms-word://
```

I get the notification that my browser tries to open a local application. But when I am using that same logic in a custom created JSON button on a SharePoint Online it just disappears and it's not working.


The button should be formatted in JSON. And at the moment it looks like this

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "Open in client App",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "class": "sp-field-quickAction",
    "href": "ms-word://"
  }
}
```

When I create a tinyurl with the same ms-word:// and put that in place it works like a charm.
Unfortunately I'll have to do this for like 350 different lists :-)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Per my research, this feature has not been implemented.

Please refer to the same request:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/38773372-allow-office-schema-uri-in-json-formatting-href

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/5545