# How can I open a local application with a link/button/shortcut from SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online

Our organization uses SPO for internal communication.  So, we have a number of Team sites built for different groups.  On the appropriate Team sites, I'd like to add a shortcuts/links/buttons to open a few of our legacy desktop applications (e.g. an RMS program and a timecard program).  Basically, I want to run an .exe from SPO, similar to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/282199/open-local-app-from-button-on-sharepoint-online-list), but opening a non-MS application.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can register your applications to a URI scheme according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85).

Example:
You can have a URL *thisapp:var1* which will run an app in the user's PC *C:\Program Files\thisapp.exe* by registering your application to a URI scheme in Windows.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    thisapp
        (Default) = "URL:thisapp link"
        URL Protocol = ""
        shell
            open
                command
                    (Default) = "C:\Program Files\thisapp.exe" "%1"
```

Test it on your PC first to understand how it works.

Next:

- Deploy the registry entry using Group Policy to your organization so that all PC will have this URL protocol.
- Ensure that all PCs have installed the application you want to run with this protocol **with the same path**.
- Then you can set up a SharePoint page contains all apps' URL protocol to launch it and plug it into a tab in Teams or put it under your Team sites.

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work from a browser, but I can't get it to make the jump to SPO.  All the web parts that seem appropriate (e.g. links) require https.  Any thoughts on how to execute from SPO?

Answer (score 1):

That would not be possible using JSON formatting if that’s what you plan.

You can create custom hyperlink using custom code like JavaScript and embed it using [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

See a few references here: [How to run a exe file using a java script.](https://forums.asp.net/t/1729458.aspx?How%20to%20run%20a%20exe%20file%20using%20a%20java%20script) /
[Run local exe file from href link and SharePoint Top Navigation.](https://sharepointqna.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/run-local-exe-file-from-href-link/)